# Limit number of orders to delete SQL Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin

I have this query below to delete all Woocommerce orders. Does anyone know how I modify this query to delete only the first 500 orders. reason being my system times out.

```
DELETE FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta;
DELETE FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items;
DELETE FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_type = 'order_note';
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN ( SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' );
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order';
```

Comment: What do you mean by "first"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LIMIT` clause with your `DELETE` query just fine:

```sql
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' LIMIT 500;
```